# NEW "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException" Problem

Tags: jquery, hover, domexception

Have a look at the following page and before clicking anywhere in it, hover over the video and check your console - an error is thrown and the video doesn't play...

https://codepen.io/gil--/pen/bNxZWg

Jquery code:

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

**ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException**

However, when you click somewhere on the page and then hover the video, it plays and no errors are thrown.
I'm using the same code on my site hence, I'd like to fix it.
This is super strange!

Comment: Please don't try and get around the errors the system is showing you. The reason we ask for code is not to get you to format text as code, but to allow people to see the code without having to go to another site. Please respect the time of the volunteers trying to help you and include the code here. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to insert your code here.

Comment: Apologies, edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because there is a new "rule", since 2016, about triggering a video play in most "modern" browsers. [See this Google's dev blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise). It now requires the user to "interact" with the page at least once before the programatical trigger.

So I suggest you to fing a way to have the user at least click somewere in your webpage... Be it a nearly useless button and a flag to make sure to prevent the error.

Have a look below. Also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yweyzK?editors=1010)

I'm sure you can have that button (or any click invitation) cuter ;)

```js
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
  if(playEnabled){ 
    $('video', this).get(0).play();
  }
}

function hideVideo(e) {
  if(playEnabled){
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
  }
}

var playEnabled = false;
$("#enablePlay").on("click",function(){
  playEnabled = true;
  $(this).html("Video play enabled!");
});
```

```css
#videosList {
 max-width: 600px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video {
  background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/nZcejtAwxz4/maxresdefault.jpg');
  height: 330px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Hide Play button + controls on iOS */
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
Data: https://gfycat.com/cajax/get/VerifiableTerrificHind
 
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZcejtAwxz4

More info on youtube api for thumbnails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api
-->
<div id="videosList">           

<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  Hover mouse over video. Desktop only [ Obviously! ;) ]
</div>
<button id="enablePlay">Click here to play the video on mouse over</button>
```