# How to make HTML audio tag work in Opera?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

i'm trying to add autoplay audio in my html page and i already tried embed and audio with and without controls and optional attributes, and absolute path. Tried different formats, though i know that Opera supports .ogg. My last try is here:

```
<audio controls id="music1">
    <source src="./models/laughing.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

html page and audio file are located like this:

[image: image of problem]

if i press play button audio is played, but when i start my entire project the button is covered (as should be). And anyway i want it to be autoplay so
My Opera is the last version, Windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NEW "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException" Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932111/new-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-problem)

Comment: The [canplaythrough event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) might be what is missing.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, no, even when i click on the page audio is silent

Comment: A user interaction is needed to allow a `play()`. A click on the page is not making the `autoplay` attribute to work... And that click most probably occurs after the autoplay has been disccarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoplay doesn't typically work.  You need some sort of user interaction, like a click.

There is nothing you can really do about this.  It's a browser "feature" to prevent ads from playing audio in the background.

Comment: but to enable the key interface i have to click. but the audio is still silent

Comment: @Den Audio will remain paused until you call `.play()` on the audio element.  You can do this in the handler for the click event.

Comment: gosh guess i tired. creating var laughing = document.getElementById("music1"); and then adding laughing.play(); in the event when W is pressed helped

Answer (score -2):

```
<audio controls autoplay>
```

Try adding "autoplay" inside the voice tag.

Comment: i forgot to include it in my question. autoplay is in the code, but still it doesn't work